# scala play 2.1 serve JSON response as text/json

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm running Play! 2.2 with scala. I am trying to serve a JSON response. The following code will serve a response as `application/json`, however I want it to serve `text/json`.

I found some documentation here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaJsonRequests
However, the examples shown return `application/json`.

Here is an example of my function in the controller:

```
  def myContollerFunction = Action(parse.json) { request =>
     (request.body \ "foo").asOpt[String].map { foo =>
        Ok(Json.toJson(Map("foo" -> foo)))
     }}.getOrElse { 
       BadRequest("foo bar")
     }
   }
```

Here is an example output from cURL:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `.as("text/json")` to your result. (see [play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaResults))

Complete example:

```
def myContollerFunction = Action(parse.json) { request =>
   (request.body \ "foo").asOpt[String].map { foo =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(Map("foo" -> foo))).as("text/json")
   }}.getOrElse { 
      BadRequest("foo bar")
   }
}
```

That being said, it seems that `application/json` is the correct type for JSON data, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type).